# Old Questions that Answer Your Own

Tags: discussion

I was about to ask a question on the Mathematics page when I noticed it had already been asked(3 months ago). I looked at it and found the answer didn't clarify the situation for me. Do I post my own new question since I wasn't able to understand the answer on the old question, or do I comment on the old question asking for additional help?

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4108/clarify-an-old-answer and other posts shown there among linked questions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would post a new question, with a link to the old one, explaining exactly where my specific problem was, and why the old question didn't clarify me enough.

Answer (score 4):

I think at this point it would be best to comment to see if anyone will add any additional information for clarification/justification. If there has been no positive feedback, then go ahead and submit the question with whatever you are clear on.